# Eclipse export runnable jar configuration

Tags: eclipse, jar, runnable

I am using the eclipse option to export a runnable jar from a project that I am editing. ( I have created some additional functionality through a plugin).

The runnable jar file works fine, except that is does not load the plugin I have created.

So ,I assume that I have to inform somehow eclipse to include the files I have created.
In other words,(forgive if I am asking something simple or obvious) how eclipse knows about the dependencies and all that staff ?

Since the project contained already an ant file for building and compiling ,I am wondering if this is what I have to tune.

Comment: It does not load the plugin you've created? Plugin for what? Eclipse?

Comment: Maybe I wasn't very precise. There was an existing project ,that enable easily through its ant file new plugins to be created. So, I created one, and it worked fine when I run the application manually, through its main class. The problem appears when I try to export it as a runnable jar file ;the plugin somehow vanishes. That's why I asked how the eclipse "knows" the dependencies of a project.

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by plugins.  Is this a maven project?  In that case you probably want to use the maven shade plugin, not eclipse's "create runnable jar"

Comment: I'm quite sure that it's not a maven project.Maybe the term plugin is wrong. It's better to say that its an extension on the main application:it adds some extra features.The application is rapidminer-a machine learning tool. There were some instructions about how to create extensions that I followed. I don't know if this is any helpful to you, but I have noticed that a new jar file which contains the extra features has been created in a new directory called plugins inside the lib directory of the project. I assume, that I have to make  eclipse to see this new jar file somehow.

Comment: Could you explain the directory structure of this project?  I think I understand what's going on, but I'm not certain.  Specifically, where is this new jar file created?

Comment: Inside the project directory there is a folder called lib where all the jar files  are located . Inside the lib folder there are also some others folders each one with jar files that have to do with extensions/plugins - one of those folders is the jar file that I have created. Sorry for not posting this previously -here is the build.xml : [link](http://fossies.org/linux/misc/rapidminer-5.3.008.zip:a/rapidminer/build.xml)

Comment: I gave the best guess I could as an answer, but it seems like this question is really specific to rapidminer.  The "plugin" you built is a plugin to rapidminer.  There is no default concept of plugins for arbitrary java programs.  In the future if you want better responses to a question like this, you should mention the application your building off of (in this case, rapidminer) not only in the body of the question, but in the title as well so to attract people with experience with that application

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does not use the build.xml file to export jars.  The dependencies information is kept in the .project file.

You can add your plugin as follows:

Right-click your project and select properties, then go to "Java Build Path" and select the "Libraries" tab.  Add your jar here to get eclipse to recognize it as part of the project.  Next go to the "Order and Export" tab.  Select your jar-file here so it gets exported with the runnable jar.

When you build the jar file, make sure to select "Package required libraries into generated JAR" rather than "Extract required libraries into generated JAR".  Unfortunately, I can't guarantee this will work.  It sounds like rapidminer loads plugins by searching the libs directory.  I don't know if it will be smart enough to recognize when it's running from a jar file and look inside the jar file it's running from rather than in the working directory.

If not, you'll have to ask your question to someone who knows about rapidminer.

Comment: As you have already guessed if I export  with the option" Package required libraries into generated JAR" the jar file does not load. I ll try to see if I can fix this (It needs another thread) and let you know if your suggestion works.